# Why does QGIS's Clipper tell me "Computed -srcwin falls outside raster size" and how do I address it?

Tags: qgis, raster, clip

I'm trying to clip a heightmap to a small area that I'm interested in. When I attempt to use Raster > Extraction > Clipper I get an error dialog with the message ""Computed -srcwin falls outside raster size of..." with the dimensions.

I tried to select a smaller area but continue to get the error message and am not sure what it's complaining about and how to resolve the issue so I can clip the heightmap.

What am I doing wrong or need to adjust?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems a SRS problem. What's the coordinate reference system of your project?
Your x coordinates seem wrong.

Comment: Looks like the project was set to Google Mercator 900913 while my raster and vectors are at WGS 84. I switched the project to WGS 84 (with on-the-fly checked) and the clipper works now. Thanks!